# Use robot to click and type in Microsoft Word not working

Tags: java, ui-automation, awtrobot

I created the following code to do the following:

1. Create a new Word file and open it
2. Check the task manager to see if it did open and then continue
3. Use a Robot class to move to the centre of the screen, then click on the Word application and type: <kbd>Y</kbd>.

It is doing everything except typing <kbd>Y</kbd>.

Code:

```
// Open Word Document
public boolean openWordDoc(String tempProName, String URL, String j) throws IOException, AWTException {

    boolean result = false;

    String userHomeFolder = System.getProperty("user.home");
    File textFile = new File((userHomeFolder + "/Desktop"), j + " " + URL);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(textFile));
    out.close();
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        Desktop fD = Desktop.getDesktop();
        fD.open(textFile);
    }

    // See if it really did open and wait until it opened to continue
    String line = "";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((!line.equals("WINWORD.EXE"))) {
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] templine = line.split(" ");
            if (templine[0].equals("WINWORD.EXE")) {
                line = "WINWORD.EXE"; 
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Robot
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;

    x = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth() / 2;
    y = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight() / 2;

    int xx = (int) Math.round(x);
    int yy = (int) Math.round(y);

    robot.mouseMove(xx, yy);

    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a popup window always opens in the middle of the screen it's safe to say that:

```
Dimension middle = new Dimension(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth() / 2, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight() / 2);
```

Returns the excact middle of the screen. Now you'd have to move the cursor relative to the middle to where the button is. To do this you could just try over and over again, but you could also set up a while loop that tells you where the button is. Like this:

```
while(true){
    System.out.println(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation());
}
```

Now you know where the button is on the screen but now you should make it relative to the middle so that this will work on any screen any size. Therefore you'd have to take the difference in x and y. Now that you know where the button is relative to the middle you can say:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(middle.getWidth() + differenceX, middle.getHeight() + differenceY);
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
```

Note that this way is not entirely safe. If the user manages to move the popup before it's clicked the code will click somewhere else.
But for the rest I belive that this code will work and on all monitors. But I haven't tested it. And you may need to let the robot click twice once to gain focus and an other time to actually click. If you have any more questions don't hesitate to ask them.

I hope this works.
Key press code:

```
// Robot
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;

    x = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth() / 2;
    y = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight() / 2;

    int xx = (int) Math.round(x);
    int yy = (int) Math.round(y);

    robot.mouseMove(xx, yy);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
```

You should be able to see where it goes.
I hope this works :).

Comment: Ok so I am just playing around with it in Word, so far it seems to work thanks :).

Comment: Wow this question is so bad I can no longer ask another 1. Can you maybe help me though it is related the question above and this time I have code... I am opening MircoSoft Word using Java then using the robot to click and then to type for some reason the click is being accepted but the typing not. When I say accepted I mean the click is registering and the type code is taking place but the letters are not appearing on Word. I can send you the code.

Comment: Well I see that your question is indeed not very accepted... But I do not agree with the people that said it was unclear (how else could I've answered?). But yeah I'll help you with the typing code. This code works for me to press a key (as long as the window has focus) `new Robot().keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);`  p.s. you can also upvote this answer ._.

Comment: I can't because I have a bad reputation, I've tried. Ok so the code you posted is what I am using but it is not working. I can't post my code here can I sent it to you ?

Comment: You can edit your question or I can create a new (public) chatroom. You can choose.

Comment: Sure I also just noticed this question looks smiliar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230252/robot-class-keypress-not-working

Comment: Yes that was my question, I didn't realise I could edit this one.

Comment: Hold on I think that answer might be it --- Nope wasn't. Anyway I'll close that one.

Comment: I don't think so because I worked for me with only key presses. But I noticed you did not explicitly gain the focus of word.

Comment: Try to let the robot click on word and after that start typing.

Comment: Yes I don't know how to explicitly gain the focus, I have tried a few WindowFocus methods like: requestfocus and set focused window state, but I can't get it working. My thinking was that if I get the robot to click on the Word application then the focus will be on it and I can type.

Comment: Solved it I think adding it to my answer now.

Comment: Awesum let me take a look. Also I was googling and found these pretty usefull CMD prompts to get windows focused etc: http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/index.html

Comment: Ah man it's working thanks a lot ! If I could upvote I would.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed you need 15 rep to do that :( But anyways good luck with the reset of your code after all this is a Q&A site. And maybe later sometime it you remember it :). By the way I'll upvote you so you get a little better reputation :).

Comment: Also unfortunatly I can't remove the hold... But you're at 8 rep now so that should also be good :).